# Topology question regarding merged edge loop vertices

Tags: animation, mesh, topology, surface-deform

So I had modelled a base mesh for a female game character I was modelling. However, I wanted it to be sculpted at some parts but overall low poly. So I did this:
[image: model]

I joined one vertex each of 3 edge loops and dissolved the remaining edges of those loops.(similar to some hand modelling tutorials on YT)
Now I'm extremely worried whether the body would work fine in my game.
Can anyone please tell me whether I can use this topology in my game? If I cannot, then how can I improve this topology?

(This picture shows the buttock area of my model)

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look very good but it's hard to help as there must be several ways to do this part and several ways to fix what you've done, for example you could correct this part this way:

[image]